# TypeError: db.collection(...).document is not a function in firestore

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-firestore

I'm not sure if I'm missing a script here, I've made sure i'm pointing to the firestore() db and not the realtime database but I'm getting the error, I am able to add to the firestore() db already in another route so I'm not sure why I can't get documents also??

```
TypeError: db.collection(...).document is not a function
```

here is my router where I access the db from

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '********',
  authDomain: '****',
  databaseURL: '******',
  projectId: "**********",
  storageBucket: '********',
  messagingSenderId: '********',
  appId: "*******************",
  measurementId: "***********"
};

const firebase = require('firebase')
require('firebase/auth')
require('firebase/database')


firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const db = firebase.firestore()
db.settings({timestampsInSnapshots:true})



/* GET whichever article is selected */

router.get('/articles/:title', function(req, res, next) {
  const title = req.params.title
  console.log(title)

  db.collection('articles').document(title.toString()).get().then((string) => {
    console.log(string)
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/../public/articletemplate.html"));
    res.json({data: string})
  });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, the method to create a DocumentReference from a CollectionReference is `doc()`, not `document()`.  You're probably confusing it with the Java API.

```
db.collection('articles').doc(title.toString())
```